# Power BI data refresh failed

Tags: powerbi, refresh, powerbi-datagateway

A data refreshing scheduled process has been working for weeks in app.powerbi.com, but some days before it just stopped.

I received the following error message:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError",
    "pbi.error": {
      "code": "DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError",
      "parameters": {},
      "details": [
        {
          "code": "DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorCode",
          "detail": {
            "type": 1,
            "value": "-2147467259"
          }
        },
        {
          "code": "DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage",
          "detail": {
            "type": 1,
            "value": "PostgreSQL: Exception while reading from stream"
          }
        },
        {
          "code": "DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult",
          "detail": {
            "type": 1,
            "value": "-2147467259"
          }
        },
        {
          "code": "Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourceKind",
          "detail": {
            "type": 1,
            "value": "PostgreSQL"
          }
        },
        {
          "code": "Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourcePath",
          "detail": {
            "type": 1,
            "value": "<ip>MY IP</ip>;MY DB"
          }
        },
        {
          "code": "Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.ErrorCode",
          "detail": {
            "type": 1,
            "value": "-2147467259"
          }
        },
        {
          "code": "Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Message",
          "detail": {
            "type": 1,
            "value": "Exception while reading from stream"
          }
        },
        {
          "code": "Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Reason",
          "detail": {
            "type": 1,
            "value": "DataSource.Error"
          }
        }
      ],
      "exceptionCulprit": 1
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to refresh in the desktop version, but I also get an error message, inserted below:
`[DataSource.Error] PostgreSQL: Exception while reading from stream`

By clicking on the first "Applied Step" named Source, I can see the result of that (all the tables and views existing in the database) in Transform Data. From the following step it fails. FYI: I need to import three views into PBI.

I also checked it if there is any solution on the net, but nothing worked.

The database is installed on a VM in Azure with a Data Gateway. Correct inbound IPs are added to the Firewall. I also restarted the server.

I noticed that the database needs significantly more time to execute the views' query, at the same time, the data didn't change significantly. The CPU is on 100% when refreshing the tables, so it is suspicious.

Do you have any idea?

**UPDATE:**
Based on my further examination, it turned out that one of my pre-queries duplicated the records in the background, which had a significant impact on the performance. That dataset could update within 30 minutes, so Power BI timed out, but after the correction, the refresh was done by half a minute.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar problem for a few days. I temporarily fixed it by disabling "Detect data changes" option in my configuration.
Refreshing from power BI Desktop all works fine.